# Why does the Xcode 4.5 static analyzer tell me that I have a potential memory leak when I try to use __attribute__((NSObject))

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, core-foundation

I have a property that holds a Core Foundation object, specifically a CFHTTPMessageRef. I've tried using the **attribute**((NSObject)) macro to tell the compiler to treat the referenced object as a normal NSObject and handle the retaining and releasing of that object for me rather than having to CFRelease myself. I've tried changing the property to weak instead of strong, but nothing seems to work, the static analyzer still tells me I have a memory leak, and from the looks of the output from CFGetRetainCount, it would that it's right. Does anyone know why my property would cause a memory leak:

```
typedef __attribute__((NSObject)) CFHTTPMessageRef HTTPMessageRef;

@interface ABRemoteConnection : NSObject
@property (strong) HTTPMessageRef message;
@end

- (void)dataReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.message = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, TRUE);

    // do some stuff and if the message is complete, use it and release the 
    // message object
    if (messageIsComplete(self.message)) {
         self.message = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `ABRemoteConnection` as a subclass of `NSObject`… could this mean that ARC can't do its magic with `@property`?

Comment: I'm actually subclassing NSObject, that was just a typo on my part. I've updated the example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html), it looks like `__attribute__((NSObject))` is only meant to be used with `retain`.

But switching `strong` to `retain` means you're now adding another ref which the prop is going to manage for you; there's still the original ref that you have to `CFRelease`.

If you think about it, this makes sense. Imagine doing the same thing with a `property(retain) NSObject *`:

```
- (void)dataReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.o = [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
```

This works fine—but only because ARC sees the `alloc` and automatically inserts a corresponding `release` for you at the end of the scope. With a `CF___Create` function, there's no automatic CFRelease at the end of the scope, so you have to manually write one.

If you really want `HTTPMessageRef` to be as convenient as, say, `NSDictionary`, it can't just be a typedef; it has to be a toll-free bridged class.

Comment: It was my understanding that, when using ARC, `retain` and `strong` are essentially synonyms. Both should retain the object passed to it. Either way, I tried with `retain` instead and I still get a potential memory leak when running the static analyzer.

Comment: Also, in your explanation you mention that ARC sees the alloc and can insert the corresponding release, but I thought that was the whole point of the `__attribute__((NSObject))` macro. Isn't it just a flag for the compiler to let it know that it needs to treat the passed in object as a special case?

Comment: I believe the problem is that `CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty` doesn't return an `__attribute__((NSObject)) CFHTTPMessageRef`, it returns a plain old `CFHTTPMessageRef`, so ARC doesn't insert a release for it. (Also, a minor quibble: the `__attribute__` isn't a macro; it's handled by the compiler, not the preprocessor.)

Comment: I think the point of `__attribute__((NSObject))` is to act as a signal to the compiler and not represent a data type of some sort. I agree, I was using the wrong terminology earlier when I called it a macro, this is indeed not a preprocessor macro but more of a compiler flag (if I understand correctly) and really just tells the compiler to act as if the data the corresponding variable holds is a normal NSObject and to manage the memory appropriately. Maybe I'm wrong here. Is this a compiler flag or something else?

Comment: Well, a compiler flag is an argument you pass to the compiler on the command line (or an equivalent setting in a GUI IDE), like `-g` for "include debug info". A `#pragma` often does the equivalent of a compiler flag on a line-by-line instead of file-by-file basis, and an `__attribute__` sometimes something similar, but it actually interacts with language-level things (functions, variables, and types). As for the right terminology… I believe gcc refers to them as "certain things", while MSVC says attributes are "special attributes"; I'm not sure which is more helpful…

Comment: For the more important part: The attribute doesn't _represent_ a type, but it does _modify_ a type. So `__attribute__ ((NSObject)) foo*` represents a type—and (at least potentially) a different type from `foo*` (similarly, but not identically, to the way that `const foo*` represents a type). This is why you can use it in a typedef. Anyway, back to the original question, I'm not sure whether the problem is that the compiler doesn't see `CFHTTPMessageRef` as an ARC-able type, or that it doesn't see `CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty` as an allocation function…